# Howto understand pointer on vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

```
class A {
    public:
        std::vector<int> & getIds(const int & item) const {
            return ids[item];
        }
    private:
        std::vector<int> * ids;
}
```

If `ids` is a pointer on a vector of ints, then why the method `getIds`, assuming it uses hidden vector's get operator `[]` by index, why it returns a reference to a vector of ints and not an int as I expect. Just do not understand this.

Could you please help me to convert it to Java? Please do not give minuses, try to help.

Comment: "Howto understand pointer on vector in C++" - by learning C++ and reading the source code carefully?

Comment: No bounds checking? ...

Comment: It's not mine code, I'm converting to another language, and got stuck here.

Comment: Isn't that what your function "says" it's going to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration `std::vector<int> * ids;` says that this is a pointer to either a single object of type `std::vector<int>` or to (the first element of) an array of that type. The fact that `operator[]` is used on it in the member function shows that the second is the case.

Applying `operator[]` to a pointer (as in `ids[item]`) accesses an element (in this case, the element with number `item`) of the array the pointer points to. The fact that the type of the objects in the array (`std::vector<int>`) also has an `operator[]` defined doesn't matter because this code does *not* call that (you could call `operator[]` on such an object by adding another indexing operator, like `ids[item][2]`, or by dereferencing the pointer, like `(*ids)[2]` (which is equivalent to `ids[0][2]`).

Comment: Thank you, your explanation helped. I thought it only the first way.

Comment: To be pedantic, it could very well be a pointer to the fifth element of an array...

Answer (score 4):

`ids` is presumably assumed to be a pointer to an element of an *array of vectors*, for instance:

```
A::A() : ids(new std::vector<int>[100]) { }
```

This is very poor style.

Comment: But there is no array of vectors?!

Comment: @user2494797: Yes, there is. It's just not obvious, because C++ doesn't distinguish between pointers to objects and pointers to arrays. So you have to look at where the pointer was initialized to find out whether it points to a single object or to an array,

Comment: Which is another reason not to use raw pointers if you can help it. `std::vector` is clearly an "array".

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, arrays are just pointers (except std::array, which I'm not talking about). The [] notation just hides some pointer arithmetic.

```
int foo[10]; //foo is essentially and int *

int bar;

bar = *(foo + 3);  //This statement is equivalent to the next

bar = foo[3]; //This just means get what's pointed to 3 pointers away from the address foo
```

A std::vector is a class.

```
std::vector<int> *ids
```

just describes a pointer to an instance of `std::vector<int>`, not to the data that might be contained in it.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers! FYI, `std::is_same<int[], int *>::value` is false.

Comment: I specifically said I wasn't talking about std::array. Arrays declared  the way I did in my code sample are more or less pointers.

Comment: Look at the code I provided. `std::array` isn't in there at all. Arrays just decay to pointers way too easily.

Comment: Another example to see the difference is having `int array[10];` in one translation unit and `extern int* array` in another. Code that tries to use `array` from both translation units will show undefined behaviour (most probably a segmentation fault as soon as the second translation unit tries to access an element of `array`). Note that this is exactly the same in C.

Comment: Arrays aren't _exactly_ pointers, but you can think of them that way, and pointer arithmetic works with them, just like you can use brackets with pointers.  From "The C Programming Language", "In C, there is a strong relationship between pointers and arrays, strong enough that pointers and arrays should be discussed simultaneously. Any operation that can be achieved by array subscripting can also be done with pointers."

Comment: @HeywoodFloyd: Try my example. You'll learn that arrays are *not* pointers. The array only *decays* into a pointer to first element in many contexts. Yet another example: With your definitions, compare the result of `sizeof(foo)` (no decay) to the result of `sizeof(foo+0)` (decay forced by pointer arithmetic).

Comment: Also note that the text you quote does *not* say they are the same. It says that there is a *strong relationship* (which is true), and that they should be discussed *together* (a statement which would not even make sense if they were the same).